# ExtJS - Sending POST and PUT requests with an object

Tags: api, rest, extjs

Quick question: can I use this:

```
// POST /users
{
  user:{
    name: "Lorem ipsum",
    email: "mail@server.com
  }
}
```

Instead of this?

```
// POST /users
{
  name: "Lorem ipsum",
  email: "mail@server.com
}
```

If yes, I surely could use some help on how, 'cause I really didn't find out how.

Comment: have you tried actually sending the request to whatever service you're dealing with? that'd be the easiest way to find out.

Comment: That depends on your service input

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, just #rtfm.

So my API will work like this:

```
// GET /users
{
  users: [
   {id: 1, name: "Lorem Ipsum", email: "foo@bar.com"}, 
   {id: 2, name: "Dolor sit", email: "mail@server.com"}
  ]
}
```

And:

```
// POST /user or PUT /user/1
{
  user: {
    name: "New user name",
    email: "new@mail.com
  }
}
```

So all I gotta do is setup my model's proxy like this:

```
proxy: {
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'users'
    },
    writer: {
        rootProperty: 'user'
    }
}
```

Problem solved! \o/